# How do I add multiple RPC endpoints using hyper?

Tags: rust, hyper

I want to create multiple RPC methods using [hyper](https://hyper.rs/). [This is their example code](https://hyper.rs/guides/server/hello-world/). How do I add multiple methods and start the service which returns a `BoxFuture`?

Below, I have two methods, how do I merge the two methods and create the service?

```
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};
use std::{convert::Infallible, net::SocketAddr};

async fn gas_Price(_: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, Infallible> {
    Ok(Response::new(Body::from("{id:1,jsonrpc:2.0,result:0x0}")))
}


async fn eth_Transaction(_: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, Infallible> {
    Ok(Response::new(Body::from("eth_Transcation!")))
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn Start() {
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030));

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| async { Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(gas_Price)) });

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(gas_Price);

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not appear that you've tried anything on your own. Stack Overflow generally expects that you've put *some* amount of effort into solving your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I've taken in the past is to make one service act as a routing table.
I've written the service containing nothing but a match that matches the path and http method which then calls the appropriate function in each arm.

E.g:

```
pub async fn route(req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, hyper::Error> {
    let mut response = Response::new(Body::empty());


    let method = req.method().clone();
    let uri = req.uri().clone();
    let path = uri.path();
    let full_body = hyper::body::to_bytes(req.into_body()).await?;
    let val = serde_json::from_slice::<Value>(&full_body)?;

    match (method,  path) {
        (Method::POST, "/some-enpoint") => {
            let new_body = appropriate_function(&val);
            *response.body_mut() = Body::from(new_body);
        },

        (_method, _path) => {
            *response.status_mut() = StatusCode::NOT_FOUND;
        }
    }
    Ok(response)
}
```

Whether or not this is the recommended way to go about things in Hyper I don't know but it works well for the things I've built.